# Can I ask this question: How to make sticky DIY electrode pads (for TENS unit)?

Tags: support

TENS unit are recommended for many diseases but the electrodes pads don't last really long, and are quite expensive for many people.

Is it allowed to ask this question here?  If not, do you know in which stack exchange forum it could fit?

Comment: See my comment on Ian's answer.

Comment: It's not a great fit here, but DIY stack exchange may allow it.

Answer (score 3):

Overall, I do not think this question as described is appropriate.

There are a few issues to consider. At the very least:

##### 1. The question is *too broad*.

There are undoubtedly many things that go into the development of an electrode intended for human treatment. For example the conductive interface between the skin and electrode, the adhesive, the pad itself, the interface between the conductive material and the wire connecting to the device, and the list goes on. The scope is too broad to be asked in a single question on this site.

##### 2. Making mistakes could be dangerous.

In many countries, medical devices are tightly regulated because mistakes can be dangerous. Some members of this community would be hesitant to provide suggestions because a sub-standard device might, for example, cause burns.

Such a question has specific aspects which could be on topic for [Electrical Engineering.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) or [DIY.SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/), but a question there would face similar issues.

Comment: A definite +1 on this answer. I believe TENS electrodes are regulated medical devices in the US (and probably elsewhere), so manufacturing them and selling them would require regulatory approval. And OP might want to consider the liability potential. If someone puts one of those electrodes on his chest and stops his heart or fries his pacemaker, OP could potentially be held liable even if the use was contrary to directions.

Comment: They sell TENS units and pads on Amazon. They are not medically regulated below a certain power threshold. And I don't see how it is medical advice, OP is not asking how to use the unit/pads, just how to make the pads. It's like asking how to make conductive gel. There is nothing medical in the making.

Comment: Additionally, the pads are basically bandaids with conductive gel and a little nub post to attach the clip. Bandaid, KY and a snap button is all they are.

Comment: @JohnP Just because something's sold on amazon doesn't mean it's not a regulated device. You can buy many FDA regulated devices there. I didn't do extensive homework, but I did find discussions on fda.gov about electrodes and which regulations they fall under. I'd be rather surprised if they're not regulated given that they can do harm.

Comment: You are really **stretching** the applicability of the  "no medical advice" concept here.

Comment: I think OP is on thin ice making (and presumably selling) medical devices without understanding regulatory requirements and liability issues, but the big problem for me isn't that it's medical advice. It's that how to build devices of any sort simply isn't an on-topic question here. Maybe it fits on EE or DIY, but not here.

Comment: As usual the conclusion comes first ("following my gut feeling I'm personally against it" then the personne try to rationalize her gut feeling by finding any argument that could fit, or another if the first doesn't, and if none fit, she just closes the debate).  (Imagine the stress endured by the guy who invented the fork: he would have been sued in US by people who blinded themselves with it. Forks are dangerous too; they should be regulated by the FDA!)

Comment: Hey @Ian, you should have just gotten an email from me inviting you to a pre-screening session hosted by Stack Exchange. We've got dates this upcoming Monday and Tuesday, so if you are interested, could you let me know what times might work best for you?